# How can I display an ER Diagram with a self referencing relationship in yEd?

Tags: diagrams, yed

I am using [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) to create an ER Diagram. Mostly everything is pretty easy to understand, but I am stuck trying to figure out how to create a self referencing relationship since the edges always connect to the same place. I want to be able to create something like the example below. I know I can make shapes invisible and still connect to them, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

*How can I create a self referencing relationship in yEd?*

**Self Referencing Relationship**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icons in yED apparently have a different number of visible anchor points at different levels of zoom. Zoomed out, each icon may only display a center anchor point, but zoomed in, you can have 5 anchor points per default icon:

*ex. Icon Anchor Points (Green Dots)*

[image: yED - Icon Anchor Points - Screenshot]

If you pull from the bottom anchor of `Employee` to the bottom anchor of `Works For`, then from the top anchor of `Works For` to the top anchor of `Employee`, you can get a diagram similar to the one shown in your original question:

*ex. Anchor Connection Example*

[image: yED - Icon Anchor Points - Connection Diagram - Screenshot]

---

*This diagram was created in the the default Hierarchical layout. `Role`, `Salary`, `Employee_name` and `Employee_id` were all attached to the center anchor of `Employee` and adjusted manually (i.e. shape position and connection line "bends").*

---